# Custom CSS cursor disappears on space bar press and hold

Tags: javascript, css, dom-events

I am listening for `keydown` on spacebar press, and immediately removing the very same listener. On `keyup` I am setting the listener again. The callback function sets a class on the body that should cause a custom cursor to show. But with the spacebar held down, the custom "grab" cursor only shows when the mouse is in motion, and shows no CSS cursor at all (!) when the mouse is in a static position. This is unexpected of course, but Firefox and Chrome are both behaving the same way so I'm probably doing something wrong. None of the usual "force render" tricks are working for me. Help is very much appreciated.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XbzeeE

and, for the record, html:

`<div id="plot"></div>`

with CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    background: gray;
    display: flex;
  align-items: center;
    margin: 0;          
}

#plot {
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
}

.space-bar-depressed > #plot {
    cursor: -webkit-grab;
    cursor: -moz-grab;
}
```

and js:

```
var body = document.body;
var plot = document.getElementById("plot");

var handleSpaceKeyDown = function(e) {
    var key = e.which;
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();    

    if (key == 32 ) {
        body.classList.add("space-bar-depressed");
        body.removeEventListener("keydown", handleSpaceKeyDown, false);
    }
}

body.addEventListener("keydown", handleSpaceKeyDown, false);

body.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
    var key = e.which;
    if (key === 32 ) {
        body.classList.remove("space-bar-depressed");
        body.addEventListener("keydown", handleSpaceKeyDown, false);
    }
});
```

Comment: seems to work fine for me in chrome...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out: The default behavior for the space bar is to scroll down. This causes the cursor to momentarily disappear during the scroll. And if you hold the spacebar, the window will stall at the bottom of the page, essentially hiding the spacebar unless the mouse/pointer is in motion. The solution is just to eat the space bar key at the window level:

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
 return !(e.which === 32)
});
```